# Laravel couldn't start with another host on my local network

Tags: php, laravel

as we know, we can run laravel development with another host such as `192.168.1.10`, ok? now my `ipv4` in local network is `192.168.1.16` and i want to run laravel application on this host

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\diabet>php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.16
Laravel development server started: <http://192.168.1.16:8000>
```

as you see, this command can be run successful on this ip address, but when i click on that i get

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.16:8000.
```

error, and only work when i don't use `host` parameter

Comment: Are you trying to connect from another device?

Comment: @RossWilson yes, i get error too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind all IP address of your machine by running following command to run laravel

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

As **0.0.0.0** binds all your machine IP, and also you can start your Laravel application on on your desired port by using **--port** argument on artisan.

Comment: dont work any other ip address, only work on 127.0.0.1 again, like with 192.168.1.5:8000

Comment: It works with your network IP like 192.168.1.5 OR 127.0.0.1 OR localhost also when you define 0.0.0.0 as host

Comment: And if you are trying to connect from other machine make sure port yoiu are defining is not blocking by firewall, like make sure your port is open for network access.

Comment: after run app on `0.0.0.0` web app only can be open with `127.0.0.1` ip address and `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: windows firewall is disable on my machine

Comment: It works all fine when i do ilke this even accessible in whole network

Comment: problem resolve now, after run on `0.0.0.0` i can access on another machine now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run from terminal if you have already installed [valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet)

```
valet link
valet share
```